# What is the impact of upgrading the "RxFrameStartNtf" API to "RxClockNtf" API on the performance of SFAMA protocol simulation？

Tags: unetstack

I need to simulate S-FAMA protocol for underwater acoustic sensor network，but the results of the code（unet-contrib/contrib/S-FAMA/） running in the some version (UNETSIM 1.3,1.4) are different from the README documentation，and error running S-FAMA code in version 3.4.0.
What is the impact of upgrading "RxFrameStartNtf" API to "RxClockNtf" API on protocol emulation performance? and Is there any place to provide unetsim earlier than 1.3 version？

Answer (score 0):

The S-FAMA implementation (and other `contrib` folder code) in [`unet-contrib`](https://github.com/org-arl/unet-contrib/tree/master/contrib) is user contributed and not actively maintained.

Archived versions of UnetStack community releases are available at https://github.com/org-arl/unet-doc/tree/master/docs/downloads. However, these are from UnetStack3 onwards, and not for UnetStack 1.x.